# Decimal issue in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, decimal

I stored a decimal value 0.57 as number (10,2) in the database. When I retrieve the value on my screen using Ruby on Rails it shows 0.570000000001

Comment: Hi Mani, could you post some code? Which dbms you are working with?

Comment: Oracle. just printing the value from db.

Comment: Did you use `BigDecimal` or just a `Float`? How does the database schema for that database column look like?

Comment: I just saved it as number(10,2) in the db. I didnt use BigDecimal

Comment: This is called a floating point error. It is a general problem in computer science; it's by no means specific to ruby. What are you actually trying to do? Can you post some code? `number(10,2)` is not a complete code sample -- what is `number`? And why does this give you `0.57`?

Comment: insert into table (price) values (0.57)
i retrieved this value on my html page using ruby as <%=price%>
instead of printing 0.57 it shows 0.5700000001
@TomLord

Comment: @Manikrishnareddy Look at the value stored in the database. It's `0.5700000001`.  Because it's stored as a floating point number. Again, there's nothing ruby-specific about that problem.

Comment: I checked in the database. it is stored as 0.57 @TomLord

Comment: @Manikrishnareddy (This is a mysql link, but the same principle applies to other database types) https://code.rohitink.com/2013/06/12/mysql-integer-float-decimal-data-types-differences/ `Generally, Float values are good for scientific Calculations, but should not be used for Financial/Monetary Values. For Business Oriented Math, always use Decimal.`

Comment: I don't know what your question is. If it's "why is this happening?", then see the 'duplicate' link. If it's "how can I do solve this problem?", then you need to be more specific about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: i just want the value to be printed as 0.57 instead of 0.57000001 . How do i achieve this?

Comment: Read those links. For guaranteed "perfect accuracy", use `decimal` instead of `float`. Or maybe if this is a currency, then depending on the database there may be an [even better](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-money.html) solution. Or maybe you actually want to a always round to 2 decimal places? Use `.round(2)`. You need to be more specific about the actual problem being solved.

Comment: @TomLord "(10,2)" looks like the data type to me, i.e. `NUMERIC(10,2)` / `DECIMAL(10,2)` – 10 digits with 2 decimal places. In that case, it's a conversion error between database and Ruby / Rails.

Comment: @Manikrishnareddy could you show your table schema / migration, please? It's unclear what "number(10,2)" means. Furthermore, how do you store values to / fetch values from the database? Show some code, please.

Comment: table:  PRICE_CAL
          price number(10,2)

Comment: @Manikrishnareddy don't post it as a comment, edit your question instead. And provide a little **more details**, please. It seems like you're just posting the bare minimum and we can hardly give a solution based on that.

Comment: Can you please tell which class is that data? For example, let's say you have it in the variable `@num`, print its class: `p @num.class` to terminal or `<%= @num.class %>` to browser. I mean if its float you can do `@num.round(2)`

Comment: in the irb (`2.6.5p114`), running `2 + 0.3 + 0.3` returns `2.5999999999999996`. Certainly a minimal error. It doesn't happen if you do `0.3 + 0.3 + 2`, though. Not quite sure I should `round` when using sum and subtract with 2 position decimals, but I guess I must.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saving `value` as `number (10,2)`, you could save `100 * value` as an integer.

In other words, work with cents instead of dollars. This lets you avoid floating point errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [BigDecimal](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) class, and store it as Decimal or String in database

for example

```
sum = BigDecimal("0")
10_000.times { sum += BigDecimal("0.0001") }
sum.to_f # => 1.0

another_sum = 0
10_000.times { another_sum += 0.0001 }
another_sum # => 0.9999999999999062
```